# How does MATLAB built in autocorrelation function work without knowing the distribution?

Tags: probability, matlab

Since the autocorrelation function is defined as :
$$R(s,t)={\frac {\operatorname {E} [(X_{t}-\mu _{t})(X_{s}-\mu _{s})]}{\sigma _{t}\sigma _{s}}}\,,$$
and requires the expected value and therefore, the distribution of the signal, how do MATLAB built in functions like *autocorr* work without knowing the distribution? How does it calculate the expected value?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, MATLAB's autocorr function is not dealing with a "theoretical" random process but with a time series, which may be a sample from this random process.  So it's not using expected values of the distribution, but rather averages of the observed values.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Do you mean a simple non-weighted average of all the data samples over time?
can we use this estimation for evaluating any other function that requires expected value for the discrete signal?for instance,can we evaluate power spectral density using the average of fft(x)^2?

Comment: This answer is exactly right -- it is the *sample* autocorrelation, not the true autocorrelation. See the end of the documentation for details: https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/autocorr.html . In almost all statistical procedures, you don't have the population level parameters available, so you use the sample parameters to do your work.